# Saída de estruturas compostas no Python no Google Colab

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

Eu tenho essa lista chamada "brasil" e queria entender o porquê de ao pedir ela no Google Colab Notebook chamando a sua respectiva variável, a lista é apresentada em uma certa ordem e quando eu dou print nela, a mesma aparece com os dicionários que estão dentro dela de maneira invertida. Então minhas dúvidas são:

1. Isso acontece em função de alguma atualização do Python 3.9 ou algo assim?
2. Como eu verifico a versão do Python rodando no Google Colab Research?
3. Acontece em função de algum parâmetro opcional de ordenação cujo valor default causa isso? Se não, o que aconteceria?
4. O mesmo aconteceu com mais alguém?

Ressalvas:

- Sim, eu testei isso em outros editores de código incluindo o IDLE 3.8.3, será que devo me preocupar em atualizar o Python e seu respectivo IDLE para ver se o problema persiste?

  - E pra deixar um pouco mais explícito: testando no IDLE o resultado foi como "esperado", isto é, a ordem dos dicionários dentro é lista foi mantida após a chamada da variável.

Segue o código:

```
estado1 = {'uf':'Rio de Janeiro', 'sigla':'RJ'}
estado2 = {'uf':'São Paulo', 'sigla':'SP'}

brasil = []
brasil.append(estado1)
brasil.append(estado2)

print(brasil) # A
brasil # B
--------------------
output:

[{'uf': 'Rio de Janeiro', 'sigla': 'RJ'}, {'uf': 'São Paulo', 'sigla': 'SP'}] # A

[{'sigla': 'RJ', 'uf': 'Rio de Janeiro'}, {'sigla': 'SP', 'uf': 'São Paulo'}] # B
```

[image: Código acima no Google colab com os resultados]

O mesmo acontece com os dicionários isoladamente:

[image: Chamando as variáveis estado1 e estado2 sem utilizar o print, seus outputs saem na ordem inversa à digitada na assinatura da variável]

No IDLE (o código é o mesmo lá de cima):

```
>>> estado1
{'uf': 'Rio de Janeiro', 'sigla': 'RJ'}
>>> estado2
{'uf': 'São Paulo', 'sigla': 'SP'}
>>> print(brasil)
[{'uf': 'Rio de Janeiro', 'sigla': 'RJ'}, {'uf': 'São Paulo', 'sigla': 'SP'}]
>>> brasil
[{'uf': 'Rio de Janeiro', 'sigla': 'RJ'}, {'uf': 'São Paulo', 'sigla': 'SP'}]
>>>
```

Então é basicamente essa minha curiosidade. Agradeço a quem responder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Isso acontece porque o recurso de [embelezamento de impressão](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pprint) está ativado.

O [*Google Colab Notebook*](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb#) é uma aplicação web que permite escrever código Python no seu navegador.
Os notebooks do *Colab* permitem combinar código executável e rich text em um só documento.

Os notebooks do *Colab* são notebooks do [*Jupyter*](https://jupyter.org/), hospedados no *Colab*, que por sua vez usam uma implementação *Python* diferente das utilizadas na versões shell da linguagem, trata-se do [*IPython*](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

O *IPython* possui características cosméticas que o distingue das outras implementações da linguagem, [CPython](https://www.python.org/), [RPython](https://www.pypy.org/) e [outras implementações](https://www.python.org/download/alternatives/),  possui um interface de notebook baseada em navegador com suporte para código, texto, expressões matemáticas, gráficos embutidos e outras mídias.

O mesmo comportamento do seu exemplo, ordenar as chaves do dicionário mencionado no final, com outro código:

```
import pprint       # Importa o módulo pprint

estado1 = {'uf':'Rio de Janeiro','sigla':'RJ'}
estado2 = {'uf':'São Paulo', 'sigla':'SP'}

brasil = []
brasil.append(estado1)
brasil.append(estado2)

print(brasil) # A
pprint.pprint(brasil) # C <-- Troquei a menção ao objeto pela chamada pprint.pprint()
```

Resultando:

```
[{'uf': 'Rio de Janeiro', 'sigla': 'RJ'}, {'uf': 'São Paulo', 'sigla': 'SP'}]
[{'sigla': 'RJ', 'uf': 'Rio de Janeiro'}, {'sigla': 'SP', 'uf': 'São Paulo'}]
```

Nesse teste o método [`pprint.pprint( objeto , stream = None , indent = 1 , width = 80 , depth = None , * , compact = False , sort_dicts = True )`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) imprime a **representação formatada** do objeto no `stream`, seguida por uma nova linha. Se `stream` for `None`, `sys.stdout` será usado. O parâmetro `sort_dicts = True` indica que a ação na falta de `pprint()` é que ao imprimir dicionários os ordene pela chave.

Acontece que quando um objeto é mencionado ou retornado no console *IPython* por padrão esse utiliza o módulo [*pprint*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) para exibir sua representação, assim ordenando os dicionários pelas chaves.

Para ativar/desativar esse e outros comportamento o *IPython* fornece [comandos mágicos](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) e dentre eles se encontra o [`%pprint`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pprint) que ativa/desative a impressão *pprint*.

No seu código:

```
#Chamado penas uma vez em um console aparte para desligar o pprint para os outros consoles

%pprint
```

Resultando:

```
Pretty printing has been turned OFF
```

E para os consoles subsequentes:

```
estado1 = {'uf':'Rio de Janeiro','sigla':'RJ'}
estado2 = {'uf':'São Paulo', 'sigla':'SP'}

brasil = []
brasil.append(estado1)
brasil.append(estado2)

print(brasil) # A

brasil # B
```

Resultando em:

```
[{'uf': 'Rio de Janeiro', 'sigla': 'RJ'}, {'uf': 'São Paulo', 'sigla': 'SP'}]
[{'uf': 'Rio de Janeiro', 'sigla': 'RJ'}, {'uf': 'São Paulo', 'sigla': 'SP'}]
```

<sup>Teste no [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SnVR87AV_DKZc9nTjzvvezK_r6hxlvfd?usp=sharing)</sup>